# Pyomo update Set and Var to solve again

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyomo

I am quite new to Pyomo but not to Python.

I have the following problem:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.A = pyo.Set(initialize=range(7))
model.B = pyo.Set(initialize=range(7))
model.AB = pyo.Set(initilize= list((a,b) for a in model.A for b in model.B)
model.X = pyo.Var(model.A, model.B, within=pyo.Binary)
model.objective = pyo.Objective(... maximize)
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
result = solver.solve(model)
```

Next I want to update the model.B Set() and as aconsequence modify de model.AB Set and the model.X Var so I can solve it again. For example, I want to set:

```
model.B = pyo.Set(initialize=range(4)
```

Then update the model.AB, model.X and solve again.  If done that manually:

```
model.B = pyo.Set(initialize=range(4)
model.AB = pyo.Set(initilize= list((a,b) for a in model.A for b in model.B)
model.X = pyo.Var(model.A, model.B, within=pyo.Binary)
result = solver.solve(model)
```

Thats not working, it gives the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot add component 'X_index' (type <class 'pyomo.core.base.sets._SetProduct'>) to block 'unknown': a component by that name (type <class 'pyomo.core.base.sets._SetProduct'>) is already defined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to delete the variable and its index before you create it again. Same goes for the sets.

Thus, essentially, you need to add the following lines before you redefine the new components:

```
model.del_component(model.B)
model.del_component(model.AB)
model.del_component(model.X)
model.del_component(model.X_index)
```

Then you can proceed to redefine them:

```
model.B = pyo.Set(initialize=range(4)
model.AB = pyo.Set(initialize= list((a,b) for a in model.A for b in model.B))
model.X = pyo.Var(model.A, model.B, within=pyo.Binary)
```

Comment: Or you just use a function to define your model with an argument which indicates model.B's length. This is as I can't figure out why you'd want to redefine a set before solving it. So just use a function that takes one argument and loop the solve statement.